# Significance of C-3PO Powering Down

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, c-3po

In A New Hope, after Obi-wan and Luke pick up the pieces of C-3PO, they head back to Obi-wan's place to chat. At one point, C-3PO turn to Luke and says:

> Sir, if you'll not be needing me, I'll close down for a while.

The only time a droid ever turns off on camera. Is there any significance to this? Is this foreshadowing of some sort? Some way to prevent him from knowing about something? A handy way to avoid having to write dialogue for him for a scene? Or am I thinking too much about this?

Comment: It does. My bad. Thanks.

Comment: Nothing to apologize for. :) +1